# Find a certain parameter, where inequality is always satisfied

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I have a difficult problem. 
We consider the following inequality
$$ s - \frac{1}{2}\log_p(s) + \left(\frac{s}{p}-\frac{1}{2}-s\right)\log_p(p-1) \ge \log_p(p') - \frac{1}{2}\left(\log_p(2\pi)-\log_p(e^4)\right)-1  $$

The variables $s,p,p'$ are positive and $p,p'\ge2$ and $s\ge1$.

Now I have to find an expression (depending on $p$ and $p'$) for $s$, where the inequality is always fulfilled. In the binary case ($p=2$) a expression for $s$ is known (in a research paper). Here I want to generalize the problem.

I would be happy, if someone could help me with this problem.

Comment: your inequality reduced to $\frac{s}{p}+\frac{s}{p \ln p} -\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \frac{\ln s}{\ln p} -\frac{s}{p(p-1)} \geq \frac{\ln p'}{\ln p} +\frac{2}{\ln p} - \frac{\ln 2 \pi}{2\ln p} -1$

Comment: removing $-\frac{1}{2} \frac{\ln s}{\ln p}$ give that $s \geq -\frac{(p-1) p (\log (2 \pi  p)-2 (\log (p')+2))}{2 (p+(p-2) \log (p)-1)}$, which is almost true since $\ln s$ does not effect $s$ too much , so the final answer would be some tweaking around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In light of your last comment, i could give you an interval where $s$ is sure to make your inequality holds true, the only side down is $s$ might be "very far" (in sense of $\sqrt{s} , \ln s$ to $s$ proportion) from the real value.

So first treat $\ln s$ as $\sqrt{s}$ in the inequality with the assumption that $s>0$.

=> $s-\frac{1}{2} \frac{\sqrt{s}}{\ln p} +(\frac{s}{p}-\frac{1}{2}-s) \frac{\ln p-1}{\ln p} \geq \frac{\ln p'}{\ln p} -\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\ln 2\pi}{\ln p} -\frac{4}{\ln p})-1$ (1)

Let $t=\sqrt{s}$, and the fact that $1-\frac{1}{(p-1) \ln p} \leq \frac{\ln p-1}{\ln p} \leq 1-\frac{1}{p \ln p}$ , so

=> $t^2-\frac{1}{2} \frac{t}{\ln p} +(\frac{s}{p}-\frac{1}{2}-s) \frac{\ln p-1}{\ln p} \geq \frac{\ln p'}{\ln p} -\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\ln 2\pi}{\ln p} -\frac{4}{\ln p})-1$ (2)

=> $\frac{t^2}{p}-\frac{t^2}{(p-1) p \ln(p)}+\frac{t^2}{p \ln(p)}-\frac{t}{2 \ln
   (p)}-\frac{1}{2} \geq \frac{\ln p'}{\ln p} -\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\ln 2\pi}{\ln p} -\frac{4}{\ln p})-1 $ (3)

=> $t^2(\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p \ln p} -\frac{1}{(p-1) p \ln p})-t \frac{1}{2 \ln p} \geq \frac{\ln p'}{\ln p} -\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\ln 2\pi}{\ln p} -\frac{4}{\ln p})-\frac{1}{2}$ (4)

Let $a = \frac{1}{p} +\frac{1}{p \ln p} -\frac{1}{(p-1)p \ln p}$

And $b = -\frac{1}{2 \ln p }$

And $c = \frac{\ln p'}{\ln p} -\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\ln 2\pi}{\ln p} -\frac{4}{\ln p})-\frac{1}{2}$

So we are left with $ a t^2 +b t >c$

meaning that $ t > \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{\frac{4 a c+b^2}{a^2}}-\frac{b}{a}\right)$, and since $t = \sqrt{s}$

so $s > \frac{-a b \sqrt{\frac{4 a c+b^2}{a^2}}+2 a c+b^2}{2 a^2}$.

And in this case, since $\sqrt{s} \geq \ln s$ and all the way we minimized the left side and maximized the right side, we are guaranteed that $s$ would satisfy the original inequality.

Comment: I try to follow your computations. How do you get $+\frac{t^2}{p\ln{p}} $ in the second line after Let $t=\sqrt{s}$, and the fact... ? Since I used your lower bound for $\frac{\ln{p-1}}{\ln{p}}$ and get some more terms than just $+\frac{t^2}{p\ln{p}} $.

Comment: Whenever i encountered $s$ i change it to $t^2$ since $t =\sqrt{s}$.

Comment: I was trying to minimize, obviously the two terms are much bigger the the term i used, so we are good.

Comment: checked it with Wolfram, its not a counter-example, it work on my weaker inequality and in your original inequality

Comment: the left side is $\approx 10^{13}$ while the right side is $\approx 17$ so how did you do it in Matlab, you know that $s > 1.1 *10^{31}$.

Answer (score 1):

I will be proving that $\sqrt{s} > \ln s$ and that $\frac{\ln{p-1}}{\ln{p}} <1$

First $\sqrt{s} > \ln s$, exponent-ate both sides to get that

$e^{\sqrt{s}} > e^{\ln s}$ and since $e^{\ln s} = s$.

We get that $e^{\sqrt{s}} >s$.

We have that $e^x = \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$

So $e^{\sqrt{s}}= 1+\sqrt{s}+\frac{s}{2}+\frac{s\sqrt{s}}{6}+\cdots >\sqrt{s}+\frac{s}{2}+\frac{s\sqrt{s}}{6} $

We need to prove that $\sqrt{s}+\frac{s}{2}+\frac{s \sqrt{s}}{6} >s$ for all $s>0$.

Let $t=\sqrt{s}>0$, then we have that $t+\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^3}{6} >t^2$ which is $t-\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^3}{6} >0 $ or simply $t(1-\frac{t}{2}+\frac{t^2}{6}) >0$ since $t= \sqrt{s}$ is always $>0$ we need to make sure that $1-\frac{t}{2}+\frac{t^2}{6} >0$, solving for $1-\frac{t}{2} +\frac{t^2}{6}=0$ gives no real solutions meaning the graph does not intersect with the $x$-axis , in simple words the expression $1-\frac{t}{2}+\frac{t^2}{6}$ is either always positive or always negative, put $t=0$ and we get $1$ so its always positive and we are done.

Secondly proving $\frac{\ln p-1}{\ln p} <1$ since $\ln x >0$ for all $x>1$,

we get that $\ln{p-1} < \ln p$ exponent-ate both side to get $e^{\ln p-1} < e^{\ln p}$ which is $p-1< p$ which is $-1 <0$ which is always true.

Comment: Can you also proof the upper and lower bound of your first answer? Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Proving the upper and lower bounds for $\frac{\ln p-1}{\ln p}$

$\frac{\ln p-1}{\ln p} = \frac{\ln(p-1) -\ln p + \ln p}{\ln p}$

From logarithm proprieties we know that $\ln x - \ln y = \ln \frac{x}{y}$.

So we have $\frac{\ln(\frac{p-1}{p}) +\ln p}{\ln p} = \frac{\ln(\frac{p-1}{p})}{\ln p}+ \frac{\ln p}{\ln p} = 1+ \frac{\ln(\frac{p-1}{p})}{\ln p}$

So we need an upper and lower bound for $\ln(\frac{p-1}{p})$

I will be proving that $\frac{-1}{p-1} <\ln(\frac{p-1}{p}) <\frac{-1}{p}$

exponent-ate all side we get that $e^{-\frac{1}{p-1}} < \frac{p-1}{p}=1-\frac{1}{p} < e^{-\frac{1}{p}}$

Remember that $e^x = \sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!} = 1+ x+\frac{x^2}{2!} +\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots$

so we have that $1-\frac{1}{p-1}+\frac{1}{2(p-1)^2} < 1-\frac{1}{p} < 1-\frac{1}{p} +\frac{1}{2 p^2} -\frac{1}{6 p^3}$

Its easy to see that $1-\frac{1}{p} <1-\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{2 p^2} -\frac{1}{6 p^3} $ which is $\frac{1}{2 p^2}> \frac{1}{6 p^3}$ which is $3 p >1$ and this is always true since $p\geq 2$.

For the left side $1-\frac{1}{p-1}+\frac{1}{2 (p-1)^2} < 1-\frac{1}{p}$ which is $\frac{1}{(p-1) p} > \frac{1}{2 (p-1)^2}$ which is $\frac{1}{p} > \frac{1}{2 (p-1)}$ which is $2( p-1 )> p$ which is $2 p -2> p $ which is $p >2$ true for all $p\geq 2$(strict ) for all $p\geq 2$ except $p=2$.

Comment: Thanks! Could it be, that you made a mistake in the last line? Since from $\frac{1}{(p-1)p} > \frac{1}{2(p-1)^2} $ I got $\frac{1}{2(p-1)} < \frac{1}{p}$.

Comment: you are correct, i will fix it , but the argument still holds.

Comment: I am not sure. With $p=2$ I got the contradiction $2<2$.

Comment: correct $p>2$ , but since $p=2$ have a solution, according to you, there is an explicit formula when $p=2$, so you can take $p>2$.

Comment: That's true! ;)

Comment: How can you be sure that the bounds for $\ln{\frac{p-1}{p}}$ are valid, since you break the exponential series in the proof?

Comment: in the lower bound i break the exponential series at a positive term so i maximized it and in the upper bound i break the exponential series at a negative term so i minimized it, so if the proof  is valid for the new expressions then it will hold for the whole exponential series.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66658/discussion-between-n-younger-and-ahmad).

Answer (score 0):

I will prove that $1-\frac{1}{p-1}+\frac{1}{2(p-1)^2} > 1-\frac{1}{p-1}+\frac{1}{2(p-1)^2} -\frac{1}{6 (p-1)^3}+\cdots=1-\frac{1}{p-1}+\frac{1}{2(p-1)^2} -\frac{1}{6 (p-1)^3}+\sum \limits_{k=4}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k }{(p-1)^k k!} $

We want to maximize $\sum \limits_{k=4}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k }{(p-1)^k k!} \leq \sum \limits_{k=4}^{\infty} \frac{1 }{(p-1)^k k!}$ because $(-1)^k=-1,1\leq 1$.

Observe that $k! \geq 24$ when $k \geq 4$ so $\sum \limits_{k=4}^{\infty} \frac{1 }{(p-1)^k k!} \leq \sum \limits_{k=4}^{\infty} \frac{1 }{24(p-1)^k }$,

We have geometric series starting from $a r^4+a r^5+a r^6+\cdots$ with $a=\frac{1}{24}$ and $r = \frac{1}{p-1}$,

We know that $a+ar +ar^2+ar^3+\cdots = \frac{a}{1-r}$ for $|r|<1$.

**Observe that** the sum $a +ar +ar^2 +ar^3 +\cdots =ar^4 +ar^5+\cdots +(a+ar+ar^2+ar^3)-(a+ar +ar^2+ar^3)  = a+ar+ar^2+ar^3+ar^4+\cdots -(a+ar+ar^2+ar^3) = \frac{a}{1-r} -a-ar-ar^2-ar^3$ , with $a=\frac{1}{24}$ and $r=\frac{1}{p-1}$,

We get that $\frac{1}{24(1-\frac{1}{p-1})} -\frac{1}{24} - \frac{1}{24(p-1)} - \frac{1}{24(p-1)^2} - \frac{1}{24(p-1)^3}$ simplifying this by basic arithmetic on fractions we get that .

Our infinite sum is just $\frac{1}{24(1-\frac{1}{p-1})}-\frac{1}{24}-\frac{1}{24(p-1)}-\frac{1}{24(p-1)^2}-\frac{1}{24(p-1)^3}$ simplifying this we get that $ \frac{1}{24 (p-2) (p-1)^3}$ so we need to prove that $1-\frac{1}{p-1}+\frac{1}{2(p-1)^2} > 1-\frac{1}{p-1}+\frac{1}{2(p-1)^2}-\frac{1}{6(p-1)^3}+\frac{1}{24(p-2)(p-1)^3}$ which is just $0 >-\frac{1}{6(p-1)^3}+\frac{1}{24(p-2)(p-1)^3}$ multiply by $(p-1)^3$ we get that $\frac{1}{6} > \frac{1}{24(p-2)}$

the right side is maximized when $p=3$ given the result $\frac{1}{6} > \frac{1}{24}$ which is true thus completing the proof.

The second inequality to prove is that $1-\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{2p^2}-\frac{1}{6p^3} < 1-\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{2p^2}-\frac{1}{6p^3}+\frac{1}{24p^4}+\cdots =1-\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{2p^2}-\frac{1}{6p^3}+\frac{1}{24p^4}+\sum \limits_{k=5}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{p^k k!} $ which i leave for you to prove (i am too lazy).